# How can I search a specific variable in vector<Object*> in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to vector in C++, and I'm using pointer in it.
I'd like to search a variable if it already exists in the vector but I'm not sure how to do it.

**B.cpp**

```
vector<Animal*> vec_Animal;
vector<Animal*>::iterator ite_Animal;
```

What I'm trying to compare is `Animal->getID();`

And I have one more question. 
Is there any way to make a limit when a user inputs value?
What I mean by is that if there's a value `year` then, I want it to be typed 1000~2011 only. If user puts 999, it'd be wrong.
Is it possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[std::find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)** algorithm.

Probably, You are using `std::vector::push_back` or such methods to fill up the vector, These methods do not provide any checks, but one way to do achieve this is, by writing a small wrapper function inside which you check for the valid data conditions, and if the data is good then you add that in the vector or else you just return some error or throw `std::out_of_range` exception from your wrapper function.

---

**[Online Demo](http://www.ideone.com/PlPxZ)**

Here is a minimilastic code sample, ofcourse you will need t tweak it further to suit your need:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Animal
{
public: 
    int id;
};

class Ispresent
{
    public:
    int m_i;
    Ispresent(int i):m_i(i){}

    bool operator()(Animal *ptr) 
    {
        cout<<"\n\nInside IsPresent:"<<ptr->id;
        return (ptr->id == m_i);
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Animal*> vec_Animal;

    Animal *ptr = new Animal();
    ptr->id = 10;
    vec_Animal.push_back(ptr);

    Animal *ptr1 = new Animal();
    ptr1->id = 20;
    vec_Animal.push_back(ptr1);

    Animal *ptr2 = new Animal();
    ptr2->id = 30;
    vec_Animal.push_back(ptr2);


    vector<Animal*>::iterator ite_Animal = vec_Animal.begin();
    for(ite_Animal; ite_Animal != vec_Animal.end(); ++ite_Animal)
          cout<<"\nVector contains:"<< (*ite_Animal)->id;



    vector<Animal*>::iterator ite_search;
    /*Find a value*/
    ite_search = std::find_if( vec_Animal.begin(), vec_Animal.end(), Ispresent(20));

    if(ite_search != vec_Animal.end())
        cout<<"\n\nElement Found:"<<(*ite_search)->id;
    else
        cout<<"\n\nElement Not Found";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the sample is just an example of how to get `find_if` working, it does not follow the best practices.

Comment: How about sorting? search complexities? other containers?... small code example? something?

Comment: @VladLazarenko: There are template based algorithms provided by the standard library for most of the general operations. Have a look at [STL Algortihms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)

Comment: Thanks but how exactly can I use it? I tried to use it find_if itself had an error, and I was looking for it using namespace std::,  but I couldn't, is there any other way to use it?

Comment: @jcarlos: Updated the answer with a quick code sample, Hope that helps, note that the sample is for demonstration only, and it does have memory leaks.

Comment: @jcarlos: Oh I just tweaked the example a bit more to make it more generic, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could just move through the vector by index, accessing each element's ID property and comparing against your own. There's a few different methods of doing it over at http://setoreaustralia.com/ZpdHMFATCphM4Xz.php that are designed to find an element based on a series of properties